# Perlin's Noise with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, perlin-noise

I was studying Perlin's Noise through some examples @ http://dindinx.net/OpenGL/index.php?menu=exemples&submenu=shaders and couldn't help to notice that his `make3DNoiseTexture()` in `perlin.c` uses `noise3(ni)` instead of `PerlinNoise3D(...)`

Now why is that? Isn't Perlin's Noise supposed to be a summation of different noise frequencies and amplitudes?

Qestion 2 is what does `ni, inci, incj, inck` stand for? Why use `ni` instead of x,y coordinates? Why is `ni` incremented with
`ni[0]+=inci;`
`inci = 1.0 / (Noise3DTexSize / frequency);`
I see Hugo Elias created his Perlin2D with x,y coordinates, and so does PerlinNoise3D(...).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now understand why and am going to answer my own question in hopes that it helps other people.

Perlin's Noise is actually a synthesis of gradient noises. In its production process, we must compute the dot product of a vector pointing from one of the corners flooring the input point to the input point itself with the random-generated gradient vector.

Now if the input point were a whole number, such as the xyz coordinates of a texture you want to create, the dot product would always return 0, which would give you a flat noise. So instead, we use `inci, incj, inck` as an alternative index. Yep, just an index, nothing else.

Now returning to question 1, there are two methods to implement Perlin's Noise:
1.Calculate the noise values separately and store them in the RGBA slots in the texture
2.Synthesize the noises up before-hand and store them in one of the RGBA slots in the texture

`noise3(ni)` is the actual implementation of method 1, while `PerlinNoise3D(...)` suggests the latter.

In my personal opinion, method 1 is much better because you have much more flexibility over how you use each octave in your shaders.

Comment: I hope my concept is correct. If I get a few votes or so I'll choose this as the correct answer.

Comment: *Upvotes you for going back and giving a detailed answer to your own question.*

Answer (score 1):

My guess on the reason for using `noise3(ni)` in `make3DNoiseTexture()` instead if `PerlinNoise3D(...)` is that when you use that noise texture in your shader you want to be able to replicate and modify the functionality of `PerlinNoise3D(...)` directly in the shader.

My guess for the reasoning behind `ni, inci, incj, inck` is that using x,y,z of the volume directly don't give a good result so by scaling the the noise with the frequency instead it is possible to adjust the resolution of the noise independently from the volume size.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. I now understand that cjk are used instead of xyz is because whole integers will produce 0 when dot-multiplying the gradient vectors. In other words, cjk is just another way to index your texture without using integers.